# Format datetime to Month - Year then order desc

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

Can anyone help with this problem, I'm trying to select the last 12 month of dates from table, then change the format so that the date appears as:

Feb 2013

Jan 2013 etc

I can change the format to above, but that changes the date to string which then makes it impossible to order DESC.

How can I keep the above format, and still order by desc

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 12 
--CONVERT(date, NewsDatePosted, 120) AS ArchiveTravelNewsByMonth
--CONVERT(CHAR(4), NewsDatePosted, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), NewsDatePosted, 120) AS MY
--DatePart(Year,NewsDatePosted) AS YearPosted 
--datename(month,NewsDatePosted) + ' ' + DatePart(Year,NewsDatePosted) AS YearPosted
FROM dbo.at_News
order by ArchiveTravelNewsByMonth DESC
```

Thanks

George

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 12 SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), NewsDatePosted, 113), 4, 8)
AS ArchiveTravelNewsByMonth,
NewsDatePosted
FROM dbo.at_News
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(4), NewsDatePosted, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), NewsDatePosted, 120))
```

Comment: Order by column `NewsDatePosted` itself.

Comment: insert another field to store above date format

Comment: Hi cannot do that, as Select distinct top 12, I have to add NewsDatePosted to select, that then causes duplicate ArchiveTravelNewsByMonth i.e Jan 2012, Feb 2012, Feb 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try by adding an order by clause and inner select like

```
SELECT 
    ArchiveTravelNewsByMonth, 
    NewsDatePosted
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 12 SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), NewsDatePosted, 113), 4, 8) AS ArchiveTravelNewsByMonth,
        NewsDatePosted
    FROM dbo.at_News)x
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, ArchiveTravelNewsByMonth)
```

Comment: Hi no luck, I get the following error. ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified. I added the code to main question

Answer (score 0):

```
  create table at_News(NewsDatePosted datetime,Row int identity(1,1))

  Insert into at_News values('2011-01-01')
  Insert into at_News values('2006-10-25')
  Insert into at_News values('2012-09-10')
  Insert into at_News values('2002-06-20')
  Insert into at_News values('2008-12-01')
  Insert into at_News values('2008-10-01')
  Insert into at_News values('2008-04-01')

  select CONVERT(CHAR(4), NewsDatePosted, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), NewsDatePosted, 120)      from  at_News order by NewsDatePosted desc
```

Use **Datetime** column in ORDER BY CLAUSE with-out any format.